# How to run two threads in background in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, background, ios9

When my application enterBackground I need to send tow network requests, but I don't know when and where to set `bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;` to end the background task:

Here is my code :

```
__block BOOL firstRequestFinished = NO;
__block BOOL secondRequestFinished = NO;

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

                    //stopped the tasack
                    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

                  }];
```

//send first request

```
       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:[NSOperationQueue new]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *_data, NSError *connectionError) {

                                      firstRequestFinished = YES;

                                      //stop task, just if secondRequestFinished

                                    if(secondRequestFinished){

                                              [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                                              bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                     }

                               }];
```

//send second request

```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:[NSOperationQueue new]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *_data, NSError *connectionError) {

                               secondRequestFinished = YES;

                               //stop task just if the firstrequest finsihed
                               if(firstRequestFinished)
                               {
                                   [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                                   bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

                               }

                           }];
```

what bother me, is the completion blocks are called in different threads, so if both are executed are the same time the `[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask]` won't be called, How to avoid that ?

I know it's a rare case, but I just need to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting local variables to **atomic** properties i.e thread-safe, will fix it.

```
@property (atomic, readwrite) BOOL firstRequestFinished;
@property (atomic, readwrite) BOOL secondRequestFinished;
```

When you have more than one thread, it’s possible for setter & getter to be called at the same time. Atomic properties lock the underlying variable guaranteeing that get/set operation is working with a complete value.